# Why was there an 'Immortal Object' sign when Eva shoot LLENN in the 1st Squad Jam?

Tags: gun-gale-online

In *Sword Art Online Alternative: Gun Gale Online*, in the 1st Squad Jam tournament, when "Boss"/Eva shoot LLENN/Karen, the sign 'Immortal Object' appeared. Therefore, LLEYN/Karen didn't die.

But "Boss"/Eva also said something about 'Scan Terminal'.

So, why was there an 'Immortal Object' sign?

Answer (score 6):

LLENN has her 'Satellite Scan Terminal'in her left breast pocket, which is in an 'Immortal Object' according to Squad Jam rules. That is why bullets could not pass through it.

This is the same as her using dead bodies as shield, as they were also 'Immortal Object's.